Infinite sum of $(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)^{2r}$
I came across the following sum in a statistical physics context,
$$
\sum_{n=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\cdots}^\infty \left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{n}{\beta}\right)^2+1}-\frac{n}{\beta}\right)^{2r}=\sum_{n=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\cdots}^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+\beta^2}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+\beta^2}+n} \right)^r,
$$
with $r$ a positive integer, and $\beta>0$
Via the inverse Mellin transform (see Tables of Mellin Transforms, F. Oberhettinger), this can be written as the following contour integral
$$
\sum_{n=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\cdots}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2r}{2r+s}\left( \frac{\beta}{2} \right)^{s}B(s,r-s/2)n^{-s}ds,
$$ valid for $0<\mathrm{Re}\,s<2r$, which becomes
$$
\frac{r}{\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left( \frac{\beta}{2} \right)^{s}\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(r-\frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(r+\frac{s}{2}+1)}\zeta(s,\frac{1}{2})ds
$$
after exchanging sum and integral, where $\zeta(s,\frac{1}{2})$ is the Hurwitz Zeta function. I've attempted to evaluate this by shifting the contour to the left as in other similar questions on here, but haven't found a suitable deformation that reduces the integral to a finite sum of residues. Can anyone give a hint on how to proceed from here, or evaluate the sum by more direct means?
Thanks!
EDIT
Thought I would add the original context; this sum is the final step in evaluating the Fourier series coefficients $$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi} \cos (rx)\ln\left(\mathrm{sech}(\beta \cos(x) /\pi)\right)dx.
$$ We can then expand $\mathrm{sech}$ as an infinite product over the positive half integers and integrate by parts to obtain the sum above, up to renaming some constants.
For sufficiently large $\beta$ this sum becomes a good approximation to the area under the curve $\beta(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)^{2r}$ from $0$ to $\infty$ which can be integrated exactly. Due to the convexity of the function this underestimates the sum considerably for smaller $\beta$ however.

Most of this is above my head. But I see that initial difference $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ and immediately think of the obvious trick to multiply by the conjugate fraction $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$.  This trick probably doesn't improve the situation of course.

@abiessue yep, that's the step I used in the first line.

I'll be honest, that monstrosity is extremely unlikely to have a closed form (not as if my opinion matters much anyway). I am trying to see if theres some other way to evaluate your sum

If it was $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }   \left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)^{2 r}$$ the result would be $\sim \frac 1r$ as soon as $r>3$.

No idea how to tackle the sum, but I think I found a solution to the integral. Notice that $\log(\cosh(\beta x/\pi))=|\beta x/\pi|-\log(2) + f(x)$, where $f(x)=\log(1+e^{-2|\beta x|/\pi})$.
Clearly the Fourier Transform of the first part isn't anything to write home about, so I will only consider the second part.
Define $b=\frac{2\beta}{\pi}$ for convenience (and consider $b\ge 0$ due to symmetry), and note that
\begin{align}
I_r(b) &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(rx) f(x)\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \int_0^\pi \cos(rx) e^{-bnx}\,\text{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \frac{e^{-bn\pi}}{b^2n^2+r^2} \left( bn e^{bn\pi} - bn\cos(\pi r) + r\sin(\pi r)\right).
\end{align}
Now due to $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ the third term vanishes and this reduces to
\begin{align}
I_r(b) &= \frac{1}{\pi b}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+(r/b)^2} \left( 1 - (-1)^r e^{-bn\pi}\right).
\end{align}
The first sum is known, one has
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+z^2} = \frac{1-\pi z\,\text{csch}(\pi z)}{2z^2}.$$
This also immediately gives the correct asymptotics for large $\beta$.
The other sum is more tricky, WolframAlpha gives a not-particularly-nice closed form in terms of ${}_2F_1$ (so, in principle, a closed form exists. That does not mean it is very useful though).
Assuming I have not dropped some factors, we should have
\begin{align}
I_r(b) &= \frac{b- \pi r \,\text{csch}(\pi r/b) }{2\pi r^2} - \frac{(-1)^r}{\pi b}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+(r/b)^2} e^{-bn\pi}.
\end{align}
If this looks at all helpful to you, I could also work some more on that final sum; but for $b\ge 1$ already keeping just one term in the second sum gives essentially an exact result. For very small $b$ the convergence is slow, but in that limit I would consider a different approach to the integral altogether.
Here is a Desmos plot to play around with the convergence a bit.
EDIT:
For small $b$ I think I would rewrite the integral using integration by parts, which gives
$$I_r(b)=\frac{b}{\pi r} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{1+e^{bx}}\,\text{d}x.$$
Using $\frac{1}{1+e^z}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z}{4}+\frac{z^3}{48}-\dots$ and truncating at the third order already gives a very good result up to the value of $b\approx 1$ where the other representation can "take over". Evaluating the integrals $\int \sin(rx) x^{2k+1}$ for $k=0,1$ is a bit of a nuisance, but not particularly difficult.

Hey, thanks for the reply- just realized I copied the integral wrong from my notes, it should have been $\ln(\mathrm{sech}(\beta\cos x/\pi))$. That being said, I like the geometric series approach and might mark the answer as correct anyway if I can adapt it.

Oh, that actually makes it much more difficult. But I think splitting off the linear term is still a good start, the rest is 0 for odd $r$ and quite small for even $r$, too.
